# What happens if you roll a Nat1 on a proficient skill with Reliable Talent?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, rogue

If a character has at least 11 Rogue levels, they get the "Reliable Talent" class feature.

> **Reliable Talent**
>
> By 11th level, you have refined your chosen skills until they approach perfection. Whenever you make an ability check that lets you add your proficiency bonus, you can treat a d20 roll of 9 or lower as a 10.

What happens if you then Roll a Nat 1 on a roll with which you would add a proficiency bonus? Is it neutralized or is it a Critical Fail?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

### Ability checks don't critically succeed or fail.

In 5th edition, ability checks don't typically automatically succeed on a 20, or automatically fail on a 1.  It's only attack rolls that have automatic failure or critical success.

The only rules relating to critical success or failure for ability checks is on page 242 of the DMG:

> Rolling a 20 or a 1 on an ability check or a saving throw
>   doesn't normally have any special effect. However,
>   you can choose to take such an exceptional roll into
>   account when adjudicating the outcome. It's up to you
>   to determine how this manifests in the game.

However, Reliable Talent would bypass this.  The wording of the ability says that you treat any roll of 9 or lower as a 10.  Effectively, you totally ignore the number on the die and instead treat it as if you rolled a 10.

Comment: @Mindwin I don't think I understand what you mean.  Skill checks didn't have crits in 3.x or 4th ed, either.  If you want to talk about it, come to [chat].

Comment: I wish I could +More this. The idea of 'crit fail' on a 1 is so old it's time to put it to pasture. Crit fails haven't been part of D&D for a *long* time.

Comment: @Christopher: Unless I missed some detail for an edition, I think for skill rolls that they have never been part of D&D. Perhaps buried in some optional extra, although I don't think I've seen it if so. However, the idea persists, it's one of those memes that's stronger than the facts.

Comment: I remember it happening when I played AD&D, but I was a lot younger so it could be just what my DM did.

Comment: @NeilSlater Critcal success and failure for skills was an optional rule in 3.5.  DMG p. 34.

Comment: @Christopher it can't have been AD&D - it didn't have skill rolls at all.

Comment: I cannot +1 this enough.  The number of times I've had people treat 1's or 20's as crits for something other than an attack roll drives me nuts.

Comment: @DaleM Non-weapon proficiencies, my bad.